# VS2015: Static library solution for Nana

Tags: visual-studio-2015, static, lib, nana

I'm trying to implement GUI into my C++ application and I found this library called Nana.

However, the provided [instructions](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-docs/wiki/Installation) are very unclear to me, to be more specific, the part about creating a static library.

> Create a static linkage library solution within a IDE/build system you
>   use, and add all the files which are placed in NanaPath/source and in
>   all its sub directories to the project. Then compile the solution and
>   you will get a static linkage file NanaStatic in a path similar to
>   NanaPath/build/bin/IDEName.

I tried putting all the .cpp files in the Source Files folder inside the VS project but it won't compile.

Please help. I'm new to this and there are no noob friendly tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

For your convenience Nana already offers a working [Solution to create the static library using MSVS 2015](https://github.com/cnjinhao/nana/tree/master/build/vc2015). You just need to build it.

It will be good if you are more specific about the errors you got. You my need to first learn the basics of compiling and linking with MSVC 2015. I'd recommend to begin with the [Nana examples](https://github.com/qPCR4vir/nana-demo) wich also provides a working MSVC 2015 solution.

Please, feel free to ask again if you have further problems. You may want to review the [Nana forum](http://nanapro.org/en-us/forum/).